# Hosting low bandwidth site and ftp service

Tags: hosting

Before i go away and get ripped off by hosting companies offering me the wrong packages I thought i might put it to the stackoverflow community first.

We have a very small website which in actual fact will get, due to the nature of our business, very little traffic.

We also need to create an environment for our clients to be able to ftp large document files, i.e. 112mb in their own secure folders. (unless anyone can recommend a different service that is perfect for this, weve tried google apps but it won't let us upload CAD diagrams.)

What would you recommend , for a fairly novice server user, 
Would a shared environment work ?

OPTION 2:
It has been suggested that we install a server in our office, and host the website and ftp arrangements internally?

Thanks for your help guys and girls, money is a factor btw unfortunately.

Kristian

Comment: "FTP and secure" is like "drink and drive". You can do either the one or the other. But not at the same time.

Comment: Thanks mailq, the security isnt the priority , in reality we just need areas for clients to upload/download cad drawings , in an easy manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP for anything secure is a horrible idea. If you want to transfer large files I suggest that you utilize a third party service. I have had good luck with http://www.yousendit.com.

Unless you have a DMZ established for hosting your website it may be cheaper and easier to outsource that as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create needed amount of FTP-users with different $HOME for each in Hosting Panel
2. Create own site outside of FTP
3. Send user-data of FTP-accs to clients